# WebBrowser is much slower on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7.5, webbrowser-control

I have an automation task using `WebBrowser` on a new `Thread` in a WebForms project, but it is much less reliable on IIS.

When run or debugged using Visual Studio, it takes about 500-1000ms from `Navigate()` to `DocumentCompleted`.

But when running the same folder on IIS 7.5 (on the same machine, Windows 7), it can take up to 10 seconds.

Afaik all conditions are the same (same destination URL, connection, web.config). What can be different?

EDIT: Ultimately, my problem is on a particular page that is dynamically loaded AngularJS. This page can **always** be loaded on VS, but could **never** fully loaded on IIS (tested over 20 times)

Comment: Does it take 5-10 seconds everytime or just the first time you run it on IIS 7.5?

Comment: Lot of things.  Memory could be different, number of processes could be different, virus checker and firewall.

Comment: @KyleB Now that you asked, it took 500ms, weird... But when debugging using VS never took more than a second to `DocumentCompleted`

Comment: @Aximili does it always take 7.5 seconds or only first time. maybe IE security in your server test what it is before process it.

Comment: @jdweng Could they be different? The VS and IIS are on the same Windows 7 PC. Otherwise any idea how to pinpoint the problem?

Comment: Using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler will give times and help you isolate where delays are occurring.